# Python add-in: pass selected layer of combo box to a button

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-addin

I want to list layer names in a combo box and pass the selected layer name to onclick of a  button.
I could list the layer names in combobox but i don't know how to pass the name to a button. How can i solve the issue?

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ButtonClass2(object):
    """Implementation for test_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
            
        pass
        

class ComboBoxClass1(object):
    """Implementation for test_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["item1", "item2"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
         # When the combo box has focus, update the combo box with the list of layer names.
    if focused:
        self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd)
        self.items = []
        for layer in layers:
            self.items.append(layer.name)
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the classes get instantiated by Arc's opaque machinery using the variable name hinted at in the docstring.  Ignore the prefix since you're working within the same module that it's instantiated within.

So when you see

```
"""Implementation for test_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
```

it means that `combobox` (lowercase) is the instance available in the global scope and you can simply do

```
class ButtonClass2(object):
    """Implementation for test_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        layer = combobox.value
```

Note: if you have renamed the classes after the docstrings were generated they may no longer be accurate.  The source of truth would be the `id` attributes in the `config.xml`.